# Why does Jersey log a question mark for the entity in my POST request?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard, jersey-client

I want to access a REST service from my Dropwizard app using a Jersey client. Same technique works fine in different places, but in the present case the service always returns a 500 although I know the URL, etc. are correct. Since I can't modify the service I want to log my requests to verify that they're fine (because I suspect my entity is not properly serialized).

Therefore I registered a logger on the client like this:

`restClient.register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true));`

But it just never logs my entity. I always get this:

```
INFO  [2015-07-01 14:12:47,433] unknown.jul.logger: 1 * Sending client request on thread dw-admin-34
1 > POST [My URL which is correct]
1 > Accept: application/json
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip
1 > Content-Type: application/json
?
```

Does it mean it doesn't recognize any entity?

This is how I build the client:

```
this.restClient = new JerseyClientBuilder(dropwizardEnvironment)
                .using(MyConfiguration.jerseyClient) // new JerseyClientConfiguration() in Dropwizard config class
                .build("my client name");
```

And here's how I make the request:

```
Response r = restClient.target(address)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .acceptEncoding("gzip")
                .post(Entity.json(entity)); //omitting entity. It's very simple and I checked that its values are fine
```

I'm pretty new to all of this, so probably this is just some stupid noob mistake. Any ideas why the request body is not properly logged?

Comment: It works fine for me using standard Jersey. Maybe something with Dropwizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Jersey client gzipped the body by default. After disabling taht it logs and works like a charm.